# Why does the Rails Authorization header require the format Token token="abc123"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, ruby-on-rails-5

I've tried to google this, but can't find any answers. When using rails, why do I have to send Authorization headers like this

```
Authorization: Token token=abc123
```

Why can't I just send one like this

```
Authorization: abc123
```

I assume this is just how `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token` is built. Is there a downside to just writing my own method to grab a naked Authorization header, or is there some security concern I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Token` part of the header is the authorisation's scheme type followed by the actual credential [rfc1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-11). Since the RFC doesn't specify a default type, it is important to add it since different web servers might have different defaults and do different things if no scheme type is provided. There are a few useful schemes like [bearer tokens](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) and [basic](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-11.1) auth that look similar, but might be managed differently by the server. `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token` is just trying to set the scheme type for you, but if you want a different one you can use a gem that implements OAuth2 for example.